# javascript function call not looping the image array

Tags: javascript, image-gallery, function-call

created this simple image array gallery

javascript function call not looping the image array

```
var imagecount=0;
var imageArray = ["images/1.jpg","images/2.jpg","images/3.jpg","images/4.jpg"];
var allimages=imageArray.length-1;


function next()
{
    imagecount++;
    if(imagecount>allimages) {
      imagecount=0;
    }
    document.getElementById("slideshow").src=imageArray[imagecount];
}

function prev()
{
    imagecount--;
    if(imagecount<0) {
      imagecount=allimages;
    }
    document.getElementById("slideshow").src=imageArray[imagecount];
}

document.getElementById("next").onclick=next;

document.getElementById("previous").onclick=prev;
```

as i am calling the function in javascript itself the image gallery is not looping

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Are you debugging to see where it stops?

Comment: The code you've written here should work, assuming that `#slideshow` is an `img` tag.

Comment: yes its a image tag.Thanks it worked , i had two other functions between declaring variable and function that had errors.appreciate the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8VLXz/)  out, it is exactly your code and it just works to me..

This is probably a `browser` specific problem..

Comment: Its always a good practice to post code in ans rather than linking it to fiddle.

Comment: I know, but no code was changed from his original file. But thanks for the edit :)

Answer (score 0):

You are mostly likely exceeding the array bounds.  Change:

```
if(imagecount>allimages){
```

to

```
if(imagecount>allimages-1){
```

Comment: thanks,had a error bugging the code between the variable and function.